# Why when I inner join all three of my tables, I get repeating data values as records?

Tags: mysql, insert, inner-join

```
INSERT INTO Supplier(Name, City, PhoneNumber, Date, ZipCode)
VALUES ('Sandra Auto Parts', 'Akron', '330-217-1263', '2015-01-22', '44303');  

INSERT INTO Supplier(Name, City, PhoneNumber, Date, ZipCode)
VALUES ('Justin Auto Mechanics Parts', 'Cleveland', '216-227-2134', '2014-02-01', '44102');

INSERT INTO Supplier(Name, City, PhoneNumber, Date, ZipCode)
VALUES ('Mark Diesel Parts', 'Euclid', '216-223-4133', '2013-01-03', '44103');  

SELECT * FROM supplier; 



INSERT INTO Parts(PartName, DatePartCreated)
VALUES ('Hood', '2015-03-21');

INSERT INTO Parts(PartName, DatePartCreated)
VALUES('Rim', '2016-02-22');

INSERT INTO Parts(PartName, DatePartCreated)
VALUES ('Bumper', '2016-01-24');

SELECT *FROM Parts;


INSERT INTO Supplies(Supplier_SupplierID, Parts_PartID, Cost) VALUES (1, 1, 10);

INSERT INTO Supplies(Supplier_SupplierID, Parts_PartID, Cost) VALUES (2, 2, 20);

INSERT INTO Supplies(Supplier_SupplierID, Parts_PartID, Cost) VALUES (3, 3, 30);

SELECT *FROM Supplies;
```

My SQL:

```
SELECT
 supplier.Name AS 'Supplier Name', 
 parts.PartName AS 'Part Name', 
 Cost
FROM 
Supplier
INNER JOIN
Parts ON SupplierID = PartID
INNER JOIN 
Supplies ON  Parts_PartID= Supplier_SupplierID
ORDER BY supplier.Name, parts.PartName;
```

I have inner join three of my tables which are Parts, Supplier and Supplies table. My question is why when I inner join the three tables, they repeat the records more than one time. It should only be one record store ONE TIME not multiple times. Can any offer any advice? Here is my SQL code and screenshot of my problem. [Here is screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPFh6.png)

Comment: @ GurV  Do you think you could help?

Comment: when you want to get one row, do you want to add the three costs?

Comment: Also you are missing one `ON` clause in your posted query. Please check

Comment: – GurV I fixed my mistake but even without the last ON clause, it still wouldn't produce the correct results. Can you help me?

Comment: In the screenshot I see three row all with different cost. Do you want to get one row with sum of all the three costs?

Comment: GurV No, I don't want to add any of the costs. The cost column is needed to show the price that the specific supplier sells it. No adding all costs together.

Comment: @GurV How can I get my INNER joins to show records only ONCE. Daron Auto Parts has a part named Hood and sells it for $10. Justin Auto Mechanics Parts has a part named Rim and sells it for $20, and Mark Diesel Parts has a part name Bumper and sells it for $30. One record ONCE.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output in your question. Also, provide an explanation of the desired output

Comment: @ GurV  I created an embedded link of exactly how I want the desired output to be.  If you click on "Here is the output to be desired", you will the pic of exactly of what it should look in the end. I just did it in excel because it was the fastest way for you to just get a sample of what the output should look like. Thanks

Comment: @GurV  in MySQL code?

Comment: Either textual table (no images please) or table DDL and DML (highly preferred)

Comment: @GurV  is the above input good enough to help me out with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining the tables incorrectly. You want to join supplier and parts table with supplies table instead of each other.

I think you want this:

```
select supplier.name as 'Supplier Name',
    parts.PartName as 'Part Name',
    Cost
from Supplies
join Parts
    on Parts_PartID = PartId
join Supplier
    on Supplier_SupplierID = SupplierId
order by supplier.name,
    parts.PartName;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/PKYZP40595)

Comment: I don't want the Id on it though. I just want the supplier name, part name, and cost. How would I modify my code if I want to include just those column headers from those three tables?

Comment: @Smith - Where exactly am I getting the id? I am getting those three columns that you're asking. If you are talking about the 1, 2, 3 in the demo -  that's just row number of the result, not actual query result.

Comment: @ GurV  Sorry about that. I am a literal person sometimes.